# Warnings issued during compile phase of stan

Tags: rstan

I get two warnings at the cpp compile phase with all the stan programs that I submit.

C:/Larry/R/win-library/3.4/BH/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:186:0: warning: "BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES" redefined #  define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES

and

cc1plus.`exe: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-ignored-attributes"

Since I don't get these warnings in submitting other Rcpp programs, I suspect that they are generated in the course of gc++ compiling of the Stan program.  They seem to be harmless, but they are disconcerting. I see many other messages on Stack Overfkiw that include these warnings, but I have not found any explanations of them, nor ways to correct what is producing these warnings.

I am running R 3.4.3 and RStudio 1.1.383 in Windows 10 with Rtools 3.4.0.1964.  I'd be grateful to anyone that will explain these warnings to me and what I have to do to correct them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about either of those.

The first is telling you that it redefines that Boost thing, but it is redefining it to what it was already set to.

The second is avoidable if you take `-Wno-ignored-attributes` out of the CXXFLAGS line of your ~/.R/Makevars file. It applies to a different compiler or version or something and is being ignored.

Comment: The underlying problem is not in the Stan code, but in the Boost code, which Stan imports through the CRAN package `BH`.  The only way to fix it would be to hack Boost using the header guards and order of includes every time Boost versions change.  It may be worth doing that again at some point as all the false positive warnings are very worrisome to users.  I've also seen things like time-zone changes come up when compiling Stan models---no idea why those get involved.